# jQuery UI Tooltip should show Div instead of title attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

How to use jQuery UI Tooltips to dynamically show Div containers based on a given attribute, other than title attribute ?

Fiddle Sample will show my problem :

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/abooevzy/2/)**

I have different links, which can have a title attribute as well, and if there is a given attribute, Tooltip should read the value and show the contributing Div.

Sample:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="toolTipHTML" data-ttcontent="help1_content" title="test 1">Help 1</span>
<span class="toolTipHTML" data-ttcontent="help2_content" title="test 2">Help 2</span>

<div class="help1_content">
  Text for Help 1 goes here!
  <br>Lorem
  <br>Ipsum
</div>

<div class="help2_content">
  Text for Help 1 goes here!
  <br>Lorem
  <br>Ipsum
</div>
```

Currently it only shows the title attributes, which is the standard behavior. But I want to change the call this way, that I can see the Divs in a tooltip (the Divs only contain Text in this sample, but can be by far more complex in reality).

Comment: check https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Comment: Thx, I saw this, but was not able to build a working solution with the given information :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/abooevzy/3/)**.

You could use `content` option for this purpose :

```
$('.toolTipHTML').tooltip({
  show: { duration: 0 },
  hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 100 },
  position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom" },
  content: function() {
    return $('.'+$( this ).attr('data_ttcontent')+'_content').html();
  }
});
```

Hope this help.